# SLD for layers present in a table in DB

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, geoserver

My layers are present in postgis db which are being served to openlayers JS through geoserver. I have my layers corresponding to polygons,lines etc. whose attributes are stored in the same table itself. Like Halls table contain columns (hid, hall_geom,hall_name) etc. I want hall_name of each hall_geom(polygon) to be placed as a label on it in the map. I have tried SLD-styling form geoserver but couldn't make it successful(I think the styles given are for shape files and not tables in db).

Please show me a right way

Comment: can you post a link to the sld files? There is no reason why you can't add an SLD to a layer coming from a DB.

Comment: @iant, I haven't tried any relating to database but the code that is given for different styles in http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/index.html , I think they are for shapefiles........ Can you give me any link which is done for layers in database

Comment: @iant, I got thw styles working

Answer (score 2):

I had approximately the same problem : in fact, i want to place points and to style them according to "RSCP" (it is a row in my DB) : i solved the problem thanks to Filter function of SLD : here  my SLD file :


  
  
    king:mesures2
    
    
      Default Point
      A sample style that draws a point
    
        
          rule1
          BLue Square

```
   <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
         <ogc:PropertyName>rscp</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
      </ogc:Filter>

         <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#0000FF</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

rule2
          Gold Square

```
   <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          <ogc:PropertyName>rscp</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:LowerBoundary>
          <ogc:UpperBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:UpperBoundary>
        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
      </ogc:Filter>
         <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

  <Rule>
      <Name>rule3</Name>
      <Title>Red Square</Title>

   <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          <ogc:PropertyName>rscp</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:LowerBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:LowerBoundary>
          <ogc:UpperBoundary>
            <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:UpperBoundary>
        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
      </ogc:Filter>
         <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

rule3
          Red Square

```
    <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
         <ogc:PropertyName>rscp</ogc:PropertyName>
         <ogc:Literal>21</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
      </ogc:Filter>
         <PointSymbolizer>
          <Graphic>
            <Mark>
              <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#00FF00</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Mark>
          <Size>6</Size>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>

</FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```